# Trying to install Botan 1.10.0 , but getting error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, dependencies

Actullay i am trying install Botan 1.10.0 for as dependices for Botan 1.10.0 but getting the error

```
   $  sudo apt-get install -y libbotan-1.10-0
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package libbotan-1.10-0
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libbotan-1.10-0'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libbotan-1.10-0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install an old version, no longer available in the repos. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=botan <-This link shows the version currently available.

```
sudo apt install botan
```

Should install the proper version for your Ubuntu release (and all the dependencies).